# Regex: how to remove optional suffix

Tags: regex

Examples:

```
kids-and-babies
kids-girls-1224
beauty
dresses-281
christmas-gifts-for-him-3130
```

Target outputs would be:

```
kids-and-babies
kids-girls
beauty
dresses
christmas-gifts-for-him
```

I need to remove the trailing number and dash, if it is present. I get to removing that suffix if present but then I'm stuck with the trailing dash.

Comment: WE are asking this because sed won't support `\d`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-\d+$
```

Try this.Replace with `empty string`.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/7

Answer (score 1):

For instance, in .NET C#

```
Regex.Replace(input, "-\d+", "");
```

- the first parameter is the input string
- the second is the pattern of the regular expression
- the last one is the string that will be used to replace the substring in the input matched by the 
  pattern. In your case, an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

in perl:

```
perl -pe 's/-[\d]+$//' your_file
```

Test:

```
> cat temp
kids-and-babies
kids-girls-1224
beauty
dresses-281
christmas-gifts-for-him-3130
> perl -pe 's/-[\d]+$//' temp
kids-and-babies
kids-girls
beauty
dresses
christmas-gifts-for-him
>
```